# Connect MySQL Workbench to a specific database

Tags: mysql

My Webhoster only gives me the login-information for the specific database I created in their online administration-tool and not for the MySQL Server ifself.

Is it possible to connect MySQL workbench to this specific database?

Even when I put the name of the database in the "Default Schema:" input field, it doesn´t work.

To be clear, I use the same login-information as I connect to the database with php and there it works.

Comment: yes! follow these [steps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-remote-management.html)

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Sadly, I have no information about the system profile. I tryed to put the login information to the "Native Windows remote management", but the connection failed. Can you tell me if there is another freeware software out there which does the same job and is easier to handle?

Comment: check [this](https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/)

Comment: thank you, thats what I wanted